# AmCharts Force-Directed TreeMap how to hide Tooltips?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

Problem: On Hover there is always a Tooltip. I can influence what is displayed by either labelText or tooltipText but I cannot disable it.
The docs show that *disabled:true* should work but no.

**How can I just disable all the Tooltips (on hover)?**

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mx8j97ra/

Tooltip docs: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/reference/tooltip/

Tried here:

```
series.nodes.template.setAll({
  tooltipText: "",
  disabled: true // does not work
});
```

and here:

```
var series = container.children.push(
  am5hierarchy.ForceDirected.new(root, {
    tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {
      labelText: "",
      label: am5.Label.new(root, {
        labelText: "",
        disabled: true, // does not work
      }),
      disabled: true, // does not work
    })
  })
);
```